# My button doesn't send her form but another form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, input

I have 2 forms in my html code, but when I go to press the button of form2, the value of form1 is sent

```js
  function chk() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    console.log(text);

    return false;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" id="text" value="Hi">
  <input type="submit" id="submit1" onclick="return chk()">
  <label for="submit1">Hi</label>
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input type="text" id="text" value="bonjour">
  <button id="submit2" onclick="return chk()">btn</button>
  <label for="submit2">bonjour</label>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Clicking the button calls a function that reads and prints the value of an input in the first form. If you only want to submit the forms create buttons of 'submit' type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids should be unique on a page. You can use a `name` for the input elements instead.

```js
function chk(formId) {
  var text = document.getElementById(formId).querySelector('input[name=text]').value;
  console.log(text);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <input type="text" name="text" value="Hi">
  <input type="submit" id="submit1" onclick="return chk('form1')">
  <label for="submit1">Hi</label>
</form>
<form id="form2">
  <input type="text" name="text" value="bonjour">
  <button id="submit2" onclick="return chk('form2')">btn</button>
  <label for="submit2">bonjour</label>
</form>
```

Comment: @lucax979 Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

the id "text" is used twice in your code, which can lead to confusion, you should try changing it to "text1" and "text2"
And use the one you need in your function.

Comment: actually it is not "leading to confusion" but is wrong. ID must be unique. The best in these cases is that the first element with the dup id is taken into account and the others are just ignored